# Where deploy a script file to run this file 24 hours every day?

Tags: bash, shell, deployment, server, web-deployment

I would like to know if there is any place like Heroku or Digital Ocean to "deploy" a script file (shell, python or ruby) and than keep running this script forever? (24 hours/Day, 7 days/week...).

Some free server to run a bash command would also solve my problem.

Comment: A free server to run something 24x7 can be difficult to find. You can take a look at Openshift Online, but it's like Heroku and has restrictions regarding the amount of time your app can be up. https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html

Comment: Did you consider hosting the server yourself? There are several very small form factor, very cheap, very power efficient, personal computers available from many vendors. Some are so power efficient that they don't even see short duration power cuts. And they can be powered on low end batteries for hours or days...

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.